# Is Violin Outfit safe in a Airplane Cargo

Tags: violin, maintenance

I want to ship a violin from UK to Bangladesh via airplane as a cargo . Is it harmful for violin?

Comment: A lot will depend on how it's packed. Any details on the case you're thinking of using?

Comment: this product to be exact: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Stentor-Student-Violin-Outfit-Workshop/dp/B002021HIK?fbclid=IwAR08Mp6smBSKYoZg9LSs4Kk2GN3Y9mPq6-KxRuyxZ9O18AfZYfsHyMoU0dg

Comment: If you haven't already bought it, why not let the company ship it out? That way they are responsible, and would cover it. Or tell you it's not a good idea...

Comment: Honestly, for 165 pounds (US$ 215) and not being a unique instrument, I'd just ship it with some form of insurance. If it does not arrive/arrives broken, then, get the insurance.

Comment: I live in Bangladesh and company shipping would take 600 usd and in Bangladesh 60% tax for bowed instruments. I wanna avoid this 60% tax any how I can.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's always going to be a gamble.

I've had a case marked fragile arrive squashed, with obvious tractor tyre marks over it. For many years after that all my cases were marked
*"Fragile - please throw under-arm"*

I'd say if the violin is worth more than a seat, buy it a seat, otherwise pack it well, check your insurance, & hope.

There's always the possibility you could get it on as hand-baggage; even if you just have to beg/cajole the check-in desk. I do the same with my camera gear… If they start getting officious, I take out one lens & pointedly announce "3 grand" then reach for another lens. I've never needed to get a second one out ;)

If you're going to risk airline baggage-*mangling*… ermmm… handling… then at minimum, reduce the string tension; for a violin I'd probably detach the bridge & wrap separately inside the case. Fill as much space in the case as you can with bubble-wrap & then wrap the entire case in more bubble-wrap. No matter how well you pack it, you will probably have to get the post re-seated when you re-assemble it at the destination. The chances of someone, somewhere on the journey ***not*** throwing it or dropping it are quite small.

There's a psychological trick you can use.
If you pack the whole thing inside a larger box [again, with space filled with bubble wrap] making it feel light & rather flimsy for its size, that will tend to make people treat it more gently than if it's heavy & looks like it could withstand a tank running over it.

Comment: Do you know whether the low temperature in an aircraft hold would be damaging to a violin?

Comment: That & the pressure drop are why you slacken the strings. That's the best you can do, You'd be very unfortunate, on something like a guitar, if the temperature affected the truss-rod sufficiently to damage the neck. On a violin, at least everything's made of the same thing, so ought to expand/contract at about the same rate.

Comment: I was anxious about the low temperature too. Is it enough precaution to loosen the string?

Comment: If you slacken them sufficiently to take the bridge out, there's no tension at all.

Comment: From here: https://www.violinist.com/discussion/archive/29093/ I want to quote someone from the link "I wouldn't remove the bridge--your soundpost would likely fall and you'd have to find a good luthier to put it all back together."

Comment: @noobmaster69 - that's already covered in my answer. Most of the commentators in that link say they would never check it into baggage. As carry-on, it's up to you how it gets handled. If you check it, it will at some point get thrown.

Comment: @Tetsujin I am paying service to bring the Violin to me and I have no other cheap option (less than 600$) available for me to bring this. I have to bring this here as an airplane cargo. Please, give me some advice that can solve the issues raised by low temperature/pressure.

Comment: I'm not sure what I can add to my answer. If you're using a shipping company then they'll be responsible for getting it there in one piece, with insurance for if it doesn't. Avoiding the importation tax is on your conscience & between you & the government. not something we can help with here.

Answer (score 5):

As Tetsujin said, rough handling is always a possibility, and I would worry about that more than about the temperature and pressure difference. So my preferred solution would be really to have it as a carry-on.

I once flew with an ukulele without a problem. This was a low-cost airline of the kind which sells seats within Europe for 19 Euros, and makes its money off people who arrive at the gate with too-large a carry-on and are forced to give it up as cargo at a steep fee. Nevertheless, I flew with a backpack (visibly smaller than their allowed carry-on, I must admit) and the unpacked ukulele held in my hand. I didn't even have a strap to carry it on my shoulder. I had curious glances from fellow passengers, but nobody said anything, and the airline officials didn't request it to be given up as cargo.

You could call the airline ahead, or take your chances at check-in. If you do the second, I would suggest that you take the violin itself "naked" (a case will wake associations with "luggage", which works against you) and have a plan B if they decide to be too firm with you.

As for the physical effects, I can tell you the ukulele was badly out of tune after I arrived. But it has also been badly out of tune when I have taken it along on trips by car, if the climate between start and destination is sufficiently different. So I won't speculate on the effect size of lowered pressure as compared to other factors. But you have to be aware that transportation has an effect on string instruments, and even if you don't do the modifications Tetsujin suggested, you will need a tuning once it has acclimatized. This shouldn't be a reason to never travel with your instrument though - professional musicians fly frequently with instruments that cost orders of magnitude more than your violin. Even if there are long-term effects from the changed climate, they won't be devastating.

Comment: You have to bear in mind that pro musicians who do this frequently have flight cases that cost more than a business-class airline ticket, & are built to survive being run over by clumsy baggage-mangling denizens ;) [tbh, even back in my proper 'working days' I never had to take a guitar with me on a flight, always had instruments supplied at the far end.]

Comment: @Tetsujin That's right, of course. My last paragraph was meant to address the other risk, that of exposure to different atmospheric conditions (and rapidly changing at that) damaging the instrument. Not all musicians fly with their instruments, but there are enough who do. So I wanted to cue the OP that this is not a situation of "fly with your violin, and it will never again sound as nice", and while the low pressure does have effect, it is not so bad that violins should never be flown.

Comment: From here: https://www.violinist.com/discussion/archive/29093/ I want to quote someone from the link "I wouldn't remove the bridge--your soundpost would likely fall and you'd have to find a good luthier to put it all back together."

Answer (score 3):

I took a look at the case you are considering shipping it in which does not look substantial enough by itself to adequately protect your instrument. However, you might consider building or having built a simple wooden shipping crate that would be large enough to contain the instrument and its case together to protect your precious cargo. Pack with bubble wrap and padding. Another alternative would be to insure it and buy a new one, if it gets damaged.

Comment: according to this discussions here: https://www.violinist.com/discussion/archive/29093/ "I know people whose bridge get broken due to low temperature" ...Did that happen for low temperature or Due to throwing luggage by handlers?